IF/AND Formula in Data Cloud with 3 AND conditions
I'm trying to write a formula in data cloud that combines an IF and a AND statement. In total there are 3 components to the AND.
Essentially what I want to say if condition A = 1 and condition B = 0 and condition C = 3 display 'Mr'
When I have 2 AND conditions the formula works as expected
IF(AND(sourceField['Sprache'] == 1, sourceField['Geschlecht'] == 0, ), "Mr", "")

However when I add the 3rd condition I get an error:
IF(AND(sourceField['Sprache'] == 1, sourceField['Geschlecht'] == 0, sourceField['Anrede'] == 3), "Mr", "")

However this formula should work? Is there a bug in data cloud for this or am I doing the formula wrong is there an alternative form of writing this?

Looks syntactically correct to me. What is the error that you're getting here?

you should [edit] your question to include that information (when you do) instead of making it a comment.

What are the data types of the three fields? If the first 2 are numbers but that last is text, it may through an error due to trying to compare different data types. However, without seeing the error it is hard to tell.
